# Script for link redirects

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a python script, using selenium, to go into a website (Salesforce.com) and change various input fields and take screenshots. However, I am running into issues when it comes to my organization's SSO interface. My URL redirects me first, to a sign-on page (which asks for org email), followed by a page that requires login credentials before I can access the dashboard I am looking for.

For the purpose of this dicsussion, I will call the sign-on page, page #1, and the login-in redirect page, page #2.

My selenium script is able to click on element in page #1 but is unable to do anything on page #2. I have already experimented with explicit and implicit waits. But I think the issue has to do with the redirect, which occurs in the same window/tab, and not a 'waiting' period for the page to load.

Here is my code:

```
url = someurl.com
class MyTest(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        
    def login_process(self): 
        self.driver.get(url) 
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'idp-discovery-username') 
        element.clear() 
        element.send_keys("israo@cisco.com") 
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'idp-discovery-submit').submit() 
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        # login_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
        #         EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id$='IFrame_htmIFrame']"))
        #         )

    def query(self): 
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/article/form/input[6]')

test = MyTest()
test.login_process()
test.query()
```

I will also link inspected elements of both pages to help find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Page #1, inspected
[image]

Page #2, inspected
[image]

In the second image, the green box is what I am trying to access with:

`self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/article/form/input[6]'`)

Comment: I suppose that is a copy-paste identation error, but are you aware about the identation level of where you're instanciating `MyTest()`?

Comment: yes, that was a copy-paste error. fixed and thank you

Comment: Will it help if you use `self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login-button')` instead of `self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/article/form/input[6]')`?

Comment: No luck with that either. I suspect changing the attribute to find (By.ID instead of By.XPATH) doesn't fix it because selenium is trying to access elements on the previous link (page #1)? Although I'm not entirely sure that that is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)` to the end of the `__init__` method.
Or add an explicit wait into query method:

```
def query(self):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login-button'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

problematic code:

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# login_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
#         EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id$='IFrame_htmIFrame']"))
#         )
```

An explicit wait (similar to that which was commented out) seems to work better here.

I changed

```
login_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id$='IFrame_htmIFrame']")))
```

to

```
login_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'login-button')))
login_button.click()
```

and it has worked. Thanks all and hope this helps someone else.